# PWM not getting Updated in atmega8

Tags: avr

I am trying to use hardware PWM at PB1 and PB2 in atmega 8. But the in code the output values at these pins are not updated when cases occur. Please guide.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
void init_pwmA(uint8_t a)
{

    TCCR1A|=(1<<COM1A1)|(1<<WGM11);
    TCCR1B|=(1<<WGM12) |(1<<WGM13)| (1<<CS10)|(1<<CS11);
    ICR1=a;
    OCR1A=0;

}
void init_pwmB(uint8_t a)
{

    TCCR1A|= (1<<WGM11)|(1<<COM1B1);
    TCCR1B|=(1<<WGM12) |(1<<WGM13)| (1<<CS10)|(1<<CS11);
    ICR1=a;
    OCR1B=0;
}


int main()
{ 

    DDRD=0x00;
    DDRB=0xFF;
    PORTB=0x00;
    while(1)
    {
        if(PIND&(0x01) == 0x01)  
        {
            //PORTB=0b00000110;
                init_pwmB(0);
                init_pwmA(0);

        }
        if(PIND&(0x02) == 0x02)
        {

            init_pwmA(255);


        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in ICR1 is the top value (the value for 100% PWM), in OCR1A the desired PWM value.

So change the code to:

```
ICR1=0xff; //assuming, you want 255 to be your top value
OCR1A=a; //your PWM value
```

See Table 39. Waveform Generation Mode Bit Description in the Mega8 manual.